# How to sort a JSON Object from local storage and remove duplicates

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I have a list of address in local storage stored as a JSON object.

```
{"Addresses"[
  {"address1":"1111 W Main"},
  {"address2":"2222 W Main"},
  {"address3":"1111 W Main"},
  {"adess4":"3333  Main"}
]};
```

I need to sort them and remove the duplicates.

I can do this with an array

```
var addressList = ['2111 W State', '2111 W State', '1111 W State', '3111 W State'];
var sortedAddressList = addressList.sort();
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < addressList.length; i++) {
  if (sortedAddressList[i + 1] != sortedAddressList[i]) {
    results.push(sortedAddressList[i]);
  }
}
alert(results);
```

How can I get the same results without converting the object to a string??

Comment: So you want to sort an Array of Objects?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: why does each of your `"address"` keys have a number? `"address1" "address2" etc...`? You already have them in an ordered list. You could either just store the string, or if you want an object give them a more predictable key, like `"address"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your object property naming isn't very sensible. The access key should be predictable rather than relying on knowledge of an index.

```
{"Addresses": [
  {"address":"1111 W Main"},
  {"address":"2222 W Main"},
  {"address":"1111 W Main"},
  {"address":"3333  Main"}
]};
```

So at this point, you can use the technique you were using before, but you simply need to access the `"address"` property.

```
var sortedAddressList = data.Addresses.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.address.localeCompare(b.address);
});
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sortedAddressList.length; i++) {
  if (sortedAddressList[i + 1].address != sortedAddressList[i].address) {
    results.push(sortedAddressList[i]);
  }
}
alert(results);
```

---

or we could make it a little more modern:

```
var results = data.Addresses.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.address.localeCompare(b.address);
}).filter(function(item, i, arr) {
    return arr[i + 1].address != item.address;
});

alert(results);
```

Comment: I keep getting an undefined error using this, the i + 1 seems to go over the defined values in the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can read and put unique value into your array like this

```
var data = {
    "Addresses": [{
        "address1": "2222 W Main"},
    {
        "address2": "1111 W Main"},
    {
        "address3": "1111 W Main"},
    {
        "adess4": "3333  Main"}]
};

var arr = [];

var address = ['address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'adess4'];

$.each(data.Addresses, function(i, value) {
    var val = value[address[i]];
    if (arr.indexOf(val) == -1) {
        arr.push(val);
    }
});

console.log(arr);

arr.sort();
```

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/napSP/)

Answer (score 0):

For starters I would make all the keys "address":

`{"Addresses"[{"address":"1111 W Main"},{"address":"2222 W Main"},{"address":"1111 W Main"},{"adess":"3333  Main]};`

After that, you can loop through the JSON object for that specific key and store those values into an array. Finally, you can use your sort/delete duplicate method from above.

```
var addressList = {"Addresses":[{"address":"1111 W Main"},{"address":"2222 W Main"},{"address":"1111 W Main"},{"address":"3333  Main"}]}; 

var arr = new Array();
for(var i =0; i < addressList.Addresses.length; i++){
 arr.push(addressList.Addresses[i].address);
}

var sortedAddressList = arr.sort();
var results = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < sortedAddressList.length; i++) {
   if (sortedAddressList[i + 1] != sortedAddressList[i]) {
       results.push(sortedAddressList[i]);
   }
 }

alert(results);​
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LGChQ/)**

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
var uniqueSortedAddresses = [];
({"Addresses":[
  {"address1":"1111 W Main"},
  {"address2":"2222 W Main"},
  {"address3":"1111 W Main"},
  {"address4":"3333  Main"}
]}).Addresses.forEach(function(addressObj) {
  var i,address;
  for(i in addressObj) {
    if(addressObj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      address = addressObj[i];
      if(uniqueSortedAddresses.indexOf(address)==-1){
        uniqueSortedAddresses.push(address);
      }
    }
  }
});
uniqueSortedAddresses.sort();
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Jackson Object mapper, I think you could easily get a Address arraylist with a inputstream or byte[], any types you like.

Simply put it into a java.util.SortedSet and all the things done.